# How to handle Datatable paremeters in Jersey REST api

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, datatables, jersey-2.0

I'm using **Jersey** in a **REST** project and I'm needing to use DataTable in Anguler But I have problem to get parameters in REST controller as @QueryPara.
I have created DataTable Bean and get as @BeanParam but this get only Some values only not the values like array or list.
**DataTable.java**

```
public class DataTableBean {

    private int draw;
    private int start;
    private int length;
    private List<Search> search;
    private List<Order> order;
    private List<Column> columns;
    private String action;//    action  = filter


    public int getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }
    @QueryParam("draw")
    public void setDraw(int draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    @QueryParam("start")
    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    @QueryParam("length")
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public List<Search> getSearch() {
        return search;
    }
    @QueryParam("search") 
    public void setSearch(List<Search> search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    @QueryParam("order")
    public void setOrder(List<Order> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public List<Column> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    @QueryParam("columns")
    public void setColumns(List<Column> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }



    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    @QueryParam("action")
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
```

and in my Controller I am using like

```
  public DataTableResult getPermissions(@BeanParam DataTableBean dataTableBean){
```

and my Request params from DataTable are

```
_   
columns[0][data]        permissionName
columns[0][name]    
columns[0][orderable]       true
columns[0][search][regex]       false
columns[0][search][value]   
columns[0][searchable]      true
columns[1][data]        id
columns[1][name]    
columns[1][orderable]       true
columns[1][search][regex]       false
columns[1][search][value]   
columns[1][searchable]      true
columns[2][data]        id
columns[2][name]    
columns[2][orderable]       true
columns[2][search][regex]       false
columns[2][search][value]   
columns[2][searchable]      true
draw        1
length      10
order[0][column]        0
order[0][dir]       asc
search[regex]       false
search[value]   
start       0
```

I am currently using a temp solution for order like

```
@QueryParam("order[0][column]")
```

But I am not able to use this method in columns because there are dynamic columns size

Thanks

Comment: I have done this by creating custom annotation and using that annotation in place of @BeanParam.